# difficulties with openpyxl loop

Tags: python

I am trying to make a loop that copy all rows in Cell A; copying each cell one by one

```
workbook = load_workbook("D:/coding/instagram comment crawler/feed.xlsx", data_only=True)      
sheet = workbook.active
row_count = sheet.max_row
min_row=sheet.min_row
for i in range(0,300):
pyperclip.copy(sheet.cell(row_count-i, column=2).value)
```

Comment: What error are you experiencing?

Comment: so basically it is supposed to copy each text but it only writes A1

Comment: Is there any way where  i can make that loop? copy each text one by one

Answer (score 0):

Using pyperclip in a loop doesn't keep adding whatever you are copying to the clipboard; it forgets the previous copy at every iteration. Since you are looping from the bottom of the spreadsheet up, the last cell which is passed through the loop is in row A.

I am assuming you instead want to try something like adding each value to a list and then copying the output:

```py
workbook = load_workbook("D:/coding/instagram comment crawler/feed.xlsx", data_only=True)      
sheet = workbook.active
row_count = sheet.max_row
min_row=sheet.min_row
copy_list = []
for i in range(0,300):
    copy_list.append(sheet.cell(row_count-i, column=2).value)
pyperclip.copy("\n".join(copy_list))
```